# Storing &trade; within database, but also account for the entity

Tags: php, html-entities

I have got an issue within saving the ™/© symbol within my database.

The main issue is that some people will simply paste in the symbol (™, ©), whereas other users will use the correct HTML safe code (`&trade;`, `&copy;`)

This is an issue when attempting to use `htmlentities` to convert the symbols to the correct code, as if they use `&trade;` this function will convert it to `&amp;trade;`.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

For example detect if the entity was used, if so then I can use `htmlentities` to convert it.

Comment: Why would your users input HTML in the first place?! ™ and © *are* the "correct" symbols as far as your users should be concerned. If a user types "&trade;" then it would be correct and expected for your system to display "&trade;" back at them, since that's what they typed.

Comment: The system is used by web developers, but also people who don't know HTML. It should be stored in the database as the html safe version.

Comment: What does "HTML safe" mean? If you allow users to input HTML, then you must output it as HTML and not `htmlentities` escape it.

Comment: @MartynBall — It is almost always better to store the original text in the database. Escape it for the target document on the way into the target document. That way you won't have to try to reverse your escaping if you decide to use the data in a different format (like an email or a PDF).

Comment: Please vote to close question, I clearly have a reason as to why I need to do this and simply need an answer not a debate on how to do things differently.

Comment: From what I'm hearing you're trying to square the circle, so a debate is all a reasonable person can offer here.

Answer (score 1):

First, **set expectations**.

Your code should expect either plain text or HTML. Your documentation should tell the users which.

Second, **allow people to correct mistakes**.

If a user enters `&trade;` into a field that expects plain text then it should be treated as `&trade`.

Show the user a preview.

Allow them to edit it after submitting.

Trying to use heuristics to guess if the user wanted to display `&trade;` or `™` is going to lead to false positives. So don't.

Finally, we don't live in the 1980s. **We have Unicode now**. There is no need to encode `™` as `&trade;`. So if you are accepting HTML, then just display `™` without encoding it.

Comment: Please vote to close question, I clearly have a reason as to why I need to do this and simply need an answer not a debate on how to do things differently.

Comment: @MartynBall — You asked for a solution. This is the solution.